# Planes And Lines

Tags: vector-spaces, plane-curves, orthonormal

Given :Point $A(1,2,4)$ and plane $P: x-y+z+2=0$

How to find coordinates of point $A'$ the symmetric of point $A$ with respect to plane $P$

Comment: You should first explain what you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write down the equation of the line through $A$ and perpendicular to the plane. Solve simultaneously this line and the plane to find the point of intersection. This point is the midpoint of $A$ and its reflection in the plane.

Comment: Thanks a lot im really appreciate your feedback